# need help optimizing SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I am working on our Reporting database. We've been having alot of trouble with our current data dumps process, and I'm trying to rework it.

Every hour, we append data into our tables from production. Talking about one table specifically, it has just over a million rows (usually less). I need to grab those rows and append it into our reporting server table. Currently, I'm using a stored procedure that uses the MERGE process (with target, source technique). It takes about **16min each hour** for that to run. Anyone have a better idea to append/update rows? The production table that we hit also only contains **TODAY's** data, so its not like I even have to put in a date filter to reduce data load. What could be the best way to optimize performance?
Here is the execution plan:https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJrfFsTXP
Below is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spINSERT_FULL_ORDERHEADER 
AS
BEGIN
WITH ORDER_DETAIL_V2 AS(
SELECT 
'DCMS' AS SOURCE,
 DC_ORDER_NUMBER,
 DCMS_ORDER_TYPE,
 CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID,
 BILL_TO,
 CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE,
 SHIP_TO,
 SALES_ORDER,
 MERCHANDISE_STYLE,
 MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1,
 CONCAT(SUBSTRING(MERCHANDISE_STYLE,3,6),'-',
 SUBSTRING(MERCHANDISE_STYLE,9,3)) AS MATERIAL,
 SUBSTRING(MERCHANDISE_STYLE,14,2) AS QUALITY,
 ORDER_QTY,
 ORDER_SELECTED_QTY,
 ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY,
 RELEASED_QTY,
 PICK_QTY,
 PACKED_QTY,
 RELEASED_CARTONS,
 FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT,
 TOTE_COUNT,
 SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1,
 SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2,
 SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3,
 ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS,
 ORDER_CARRIER,
 CARRIER_SERVICE_ID,
 CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CREATE_DATE) AS DATE) AS CREATE_DATE,
 LEFT(cast(dateadd(hh,2,LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', CREATE_TIME),6), 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', CREATE_TIME), 6), 3, 2)+':'+RIGHT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', CREATE_TIME), 8), 2)) AS TIME),8)   AS CREATE_TIME,
 CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ALLOCATION_DATE) AS DATE) AS ALLOCATION_DATE,
 CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE) AS DATE) AS REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE,
 CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CANCEL_DATE) AS DATE) AS CANCEL_DATE,
 CASE
    WHEN DISPATCH_DATE = 0
    THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DISPATCH_DATE) AS DATE)
END AS DISPATCH_DATE,
CASE
    WHEN RELEASED_DATE = 0
    THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, RELEASED_DATE) AS DATE)
END AS RELEASED_DATE,
LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', RELEASED_TIME), 6), 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', 
RELEASED_TIME), 6), 3, 2) +':'+ RIGHT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', RELEASED_TIME), 6), 2) AS RELEASED_TIME,
PRIORITY_ORDER,
PARTIAL_SHIP,
SHIPMENT_CARTONS,
SCANNED_CARTONS,
STAGED_CARTONS,
LOADED_CARTONS,
CASE
WHEN INVOICE_DATE = 0
THEN NULL
ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, INVOICE_DATE) AS DATE)
END AS INVOICE_DATE,
SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER,
STARTING_WAVE,
ENDING_WAVE,
CASE
    WHEN STAGED_DATE = 0
    THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, STAGED_DATE) AS DATE)
END AS STAGED_DATE,
ORDER_HDR_STATUS,
LEFT(HOST_ORDER_NUMBER, 9) AS DELIVERY_NUMBER,
CASE
    WHEN  NOT_SELECTED_DATE = 0
    THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, NOT_SELECTED_DATE) AS DATE)
END AS NOT_SELECTED_DATE,
LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', NOT_SELECTED_TIME), 6), 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', NOT_SELECTED_TIME), 6), 3, 2)+':'+RIGHT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', NOT_SELECTED_TIME), 6), 2) AS NOT_SELECTED_TIME,
NOT_SELECTED_REASON,
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, EST_DEL_DT) AS DATE) AS EST_DEL_DATE,
CONCAT(DC_ORDER_NUMBER,MERCHANDISE_STYLE,MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1,CREATE_DATE) AS [KEY]

FROM OPENQUERY(MEMDWPR1,'
SELECT
OHORNO AS DC_ORDER_NUMBER,
OHORTY AS DCMS_ORDER_TYPE,
OHCUPO AS CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID,
OHBLTO AS BILL_TO,
OHCURT AS CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE,
OHSHTO AS SHIP_TO,
OHSAOR AS SALES_ORDER,
ODMRSY AS MERCHANDISE_STYLE,
ODMRS1 AS MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1,
ODORQT AS ORDER_QTY,
ODORSL AS ORDER_SELECTED_QTY,
ODORSH AS ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY,
OHRLQT AS RELEASED_QTY,
OHPKQT AS PICK_QTY,
OHPDQT AS PACKED_QTY,
OHRLCA AS RELEASED_CARTONS,
OHFCCT AS FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT,
OHTOCT AS TOTE_COUNT,
ODSP01 AS SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1,
ODSP02 AS SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2,
ODSP03 AS SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3,
ODODST AS ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS,
OHORCR AS ORDER_CARRIER,
OHCRSV AS CARRIER_SERVICE_ID,
OHCRDT AS CREATE_DATE,
OHCRTM AS CREATE_TIME,
OHALDT AS ALLOCATION_DATE,
OHRQDT AS REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE,
OHCNDT AS CANCEL_DATE,
OHDIDT AS DISPATCH_DATE,
OHRLDT AS RELEASED_DATE,
OHRLTM AS RELEASED_TIME,
OHORPY AS PRIORITY_ORDER,
OHPLSH AS PARTIAL_SHIP,
OHSHCA AS SHIPMENT_CARTONS,
OHSNCA AS SCANNED_CARTONS,
OHSGCA AS STAGED_CARTONS,
OHLDCA AS LOADED_CARTONS,
OHIVDT AS INVOICE_DATE,
OHLDNO AS SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER,
OHWVST AS STARTING_WAVE,
OHWVED AS ENDING_WAVE,
OHSGDT AS STAGED_DATE,
OHOHST AS ORDER_HDR_STATUS,
OHHSOR AS HOST_ORDER_NUMBER,
OHSLDT AS NOT_SELECTED_DATE,
OHSLTM AS NOT_SELECTED_TIME,
OHSLRS AS NOT_SELECTED_REASON,
OHEXDD AS EST_DEL_DT
FROM DSV052BDTA.OHORDR00@MEMWMS2.WORLD
JOIN DSV052BDTA.ODORDR00@MEMWMS2.WORLD 
ON ODORNO = OHORNO
')
GROUP BY
DC_ORDER_NUMBER,
DCMS_ORDER_TYPE,
CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID,
BILL_TO,
CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE,
SHIP_TO,
SALES_ORDER,
MERCHANDISE_STYLE,
MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1,
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(MERCHANDISE_STYLE,3,6),'-',
SUBSTRING(MERCHANDISE_STYLE,9,3)),
SUBSTRING(MERCHANDISE_STYLE,14,2),
ORDER_QTY,
ORDER_SELECTED_QTY,
ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY,
RELEASED_QTY,
PICK_QTY,
PACKED_QTY,
RELEASED_CARTONS,
FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT,
TOTE_COUNT,
SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1,
SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2,
SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3,
ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS,
ORDER_CARRIER,
CARRIER_SERVICE_ID,
 CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CREATE_DATE) AS DATE),
LEFT(cast(dateadd(hh,2,LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', CREATE_TIME),6), 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', CREATE_TIME), 6), 3, 2)+':'+RIGHT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', CREATE_TIME), 8), 2)) AS TIME),8),
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ALLOCATION_DATE) AS DATE) ,
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE) AS DATE) ,
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CANCEL_DATE) AS DATE) ,
CASE
    WHEN DISPATCH_DATE = 0
    THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DISPATCH_DATE) AS DATE)
END,
CASE
    WHEN RELEASED_DATE = 0
    THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, RELEASED_DATE) AS DATE)
END,
LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', RELEASED_TIME), 6), 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', 

RELEASED_TIME), 6), 3, 2) +':'+ RIGHT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', RELEASED_TIME), 6), 2) ,
PRIORITY_ORDER,
PARTIAL_SHIP,
SHIPMENT_CARTONS,
SCANNED_CARTONS,
STAGED_CARTONS,
LOADED_CARTONS,
CASE
WHEN INVOICE_DATE = 0
THEN NULL
ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, INVOICE_DATE) AS DATE)
END,
SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER,
STARTING_WAVE,
ENDING_WAVE,
CASE
    WHEN STAGED_DATE = 0
    THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, STAGED_DATE) AS DATE)
END,
ORDER_HDR_STATUS,
LEFT(HOST_ORDER_NUMBER, 9),
CASE
    WHEN  NOT_SELECTED_DATE = 0
    THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, NOT_SELECTED_DATE) AS DATE)
END,
LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', NOT_SELECTED_TIME), 6), 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', NOT_SELECTED_TIME), 6), 3, 2)+':'+RIGHT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', NOT_SELECTED_TIME), 6), 2),
NOT_SELECTED_REASON,
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, EST_DEL_DT) AS DATE),
CONCAT(DC_ORDER_NUMBER,MERCHANDISE_STYLE,MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1,CREATE_DATE)
)

MERGE BUSINESSPLANNING_TEST.dbo.[FullOrderHeader] AS TARGET
USING ORDER_DETAIL_V2 AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.[KEY] = SOURCE.[KEY]

WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 

TARGET.[SOURCE] = SOURCE.[SOURCE],
TARGET.DC_ORDER_NUMBER = SOURCE.DC_ORDER_NUMBER,
TARGET.DCMS_ORDER_TYPE = SOURCE.DCMS_ORDER_TYPE,
TARGET.CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID = SOURCE.CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID,
TARGET.BILL_TO = SOURCE.BILL_TO,
TARGET.CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE = SOURCE.CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE,
TARGET.SHIP_TO = SOURCE.SHIP_TO,
TARGET.SALES_ORDER = SOURCE.SALES_ORDER,
TARGET.MERCHANDISE_STYLE = SOURCE.MERCHANDISE_STYLE,
TARGET.MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1 = SOURCE.MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1,
TARGET.MATERIAL = SOURCE.MATERIAL,
TARGET.QUALITY = SOURCE.QUALITY,
TARGET.ORDER_QTY = SOURCE.ORDER_QTY,
TARGET.ORDER_SELECTED_QTY = SOURCE.ORDER_SELECTED_QTY,
TARGET.ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY = SOURCE.ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY,
TARGET.RELEASED_QTY = SOURCE.RELEASED_QTY,
TARGET.PICK_QTY = SOURCE.PICK_QTY,
TARGET.PACKED_QTY = SOURCE.PACKED_QTY,
TARGET.RELEASED_CARTONS = SOURCE.RELEASED_CARTONS,
TARGET.FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT = SOURCE.FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT,
TARGET.TOTE_COUNT = SOURCE.TOTE_COUNT,
TARGET.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1 = SOURCE.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1,
TARGET.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2 = SOURCE.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2,
TARGET.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3 = SOURCE.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3,
TARGET.ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS = SOURCE.ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS,
TARGET.ORDER_CARRIER = SOURCE.ORDER_CARRIER,
TARGET.CARRIER_SERVICE_ID = SOURCE.CARRIER_SERVICE_ID,
TARGET.CREATE_DATE = SOURCE.CREATE_DATE,
TARGET.CREATE_TIME = SOURCE.CREATE_TIME,
TARGET.ALLOCATION_DATE = SOURCE.ALLOCATION_DATE,
TARGET.REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE = SOURCE.REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE,
TARGET.CANCEL_DATE = SOURCE.CANCEL_DATE,
TARGET.DISPATCH_DATE = SOURCE.DISPATCH_DATE,
TARGET.RELEASED_DATE = SOURCE.RELEASED_DATE,
TARGET.RELEASED_TIME = SOURCE.RELEASED_TIME,
TARGET.PRIORITY_ORDER = SOURCE.PRIORITY_ORDER,
TARGET.PARTIAL_SHIP = SOURCE.PARTIAL_SHIP,
TARGET.SHIPMENT_CARTONS = SOURCE.SHIPMENT_CARTONS,
TARGET.SCANNED_CARTONS = SOURCE.SCANNED_CARTONS,
TARGET.STAGED_CARTONS = SOURCE.STAGED_CARTONS,
TARGET.LOADED_CARTONS = SOURCE.LOADED_CARTONS,
TARGET.INVOICE_DATE = SOURCE.INVOICE_DATE,
TARGET.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER = SOURCE.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER,
TARGET.STARTING_WAVE = SOURCE.STARTING_WAVE,
TARGET.ENDING_WAVE = SOURCE.ENDING_WAVE,
TARGET.STAGED_DATE = SOURCE.STAGED_DATE,
TARGET.ORDER_HDR_STATUS = SOURCE.ORDER_HDR_STATUS,
TARGET.DELIVERY_NUMBER = SOURCE.DELIVERY_NUMBER,
TARGET.NOT_SELECTED_DATE = SOURCE.NOT_SELECTED_DATE,
TARGET.NOT_SELECTED_TIME = SOURCE.NOT_SELECTED_TIME,
TARGET.NOT_SELECTED_REASON = SOURCE.NOT_SELECTED_REASON,
TARGET.EST_DEL_DATE = SOURCE.EST_DEL_DATE,
TARGET.LAST_UPDATED = GETDATE(),
TARGET.[KEY] = SOURCE.[KEY]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT
(
[SOURCE],
DC_ORDER_NUMBER,
DCMS_ORDER_TYPE,
CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID,
BILL_TO,
CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE,
SHIP_TO,
SALES_ORDER,
MERCHANDISE_STYLE,
MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1,
MATERIAL,
QUALITY,
ORDER_QTY,
ORDER_SELECTED_QTY,
ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY,
RELEASED_QTY,
PICK_QTY,
PACKED_QTY,
RELEASED_CARTONS,
FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT,
TOTE_COUNT,
SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1,
SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2,
SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3,
ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS,
ORDER_CARRIER,
CARRIER_SERVICE_ID,
CREATE_DATE,
CREATE_TIME,
ALLOCATION_DATE,
REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE,
CANCEL_DATE,
DISPATCH_DATE,
RELEASED_DATE,
RELEASED_TIME,
PRIORITY_ORDER,
PARTIAL_SHIP,
SHIPMENT_CARTONS,
SCANNED_CARTONS,
STAGED_CARTONS,
LOADED_CARTONS,
INVOICE_DATE,
SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER,
STARTING_WAVE,
ENDING_WAVE,
STAGED_DATE,
ORDER_HDR_STATUS,
DELIVERY_NUMBER,
NOT_SELECTED_DATE,
NOT_SELECTED_TIME,
NOT_SELECTED_REASON,
EST_DEL_DATE,
LAST_UPDATED,
[KEY]
)
VALUES
(
SOURCE.SOURCE,
SOURCE.DC_ORDER_NUMBER,
SOURCE.DCMS_ORDER_TYPE,
SOURCE.CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID,
SOURCE.BILL_TO,
SOURCE.CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE,
SOURCE.SHIP_TO,
SOURCE.SALES_ORDER,
SOURCE.MERCHANDISE_STYLE,
SOURCE.MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1,
SOURCE.MATERIAL,
SOURCE.QUALITY,
SOURCE.ORDER_QTY,
SOURCE.ORDER_SELECTED_QTY,
SOURCE.ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY,
SOURCE.RELEASED_QTY,
SOURCE.PICK_QTY,
SOURCE.PACKED_QTY,
SOURCE.RELEASED_CARTONS,
SOURCE.FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT,
SOURCE.TOTE_COUNT,
SOURCE.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1,
SOURCE.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2,
SOURCE.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3,
SOURCE.ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS,
SOURCE.ORDER_CARRIER,
SOURCE.CARRIER_SERVICE_ID,
SOURCE.CREATE_DATE,
SOURCE.CREATE_TIME,
SOURCE.ALLOCATION_DATE,
SOURCE.REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE,
SOURCE.CANCEL_DATE,
SOURCE.DISPATCH_DATE,
SOURCE.RELEASED_DATE,
SOURCE.RELEASED_TIME,
SOURCE.PRIORITY_ORDER,
SOURCE.PARTIAL_SHIP,
SOURCE.SHIPMENT_CARTONS,
SOURCE.SCANNED_CARTONS,
SOURCE.STAGED_CARTONS,
SOURCE.LOADED_CARTONS,
SOURCE.INVOICE_DATE,
SOURCE.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER,
SOURCE.STARTING_WAVE,
SOURCE.ENDING_WAVE,
SOURCE.STAGED_DATE,
SOURCE.ORDER_HDR_STATUS,
SOURCE.DELIVERY_NUMBER,
SOURCE.NOT_SELECTED_DATE,
SOURCE.NOT_SELECTED_TIME,
SOURCE.NOT_SELECTED_REASON,
SOURCE.EST_DEL_DATE,
GETDATE(),
SOURCE.[KEY]
);
END
```

Comment: This is the link: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Ok i've added the link to the execution plan. Thanks for that!

Comment: sorry yeah i actually realized that right after my last comment. I've updated the link

Comment: 71% of the cost is a table scan of FullOrderHeader - which suggests, unless you query needs all of them, that an index is in order.

Comment: You should try copying the remote table locally into tempdb instead of using a cte.  I suspect your main table could use a columnstore as well

Comment: @DaleK I do need all the columns. Although not all columns update every hour, we do have new records every hour so I'll need to grab those as well, which is why i've set it to all columns. Would setting the UPDATE part to only those columns that actually change, and keeping the rest as is, actually help performance? Also, to which column would the index be best on?

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT that's what we currently do. We save the existing data in the table (which is historical), truncate the table, get the new data for the hour into another temp, and then union both temp tables back into the table. The issue with that is that it takes about 20min to run, I'm saving 4 min with my process. Also, I'm trying to avoid truncating tables, Id rather append/update records only.

Comment: @DaleK thanks for your idea. I reduced the number of columns that were in the UPDATE statement, which I realized that atleast half of them don't get updated, so I took those out. Reduced my query time by 5min!! Big difference. Thanks for that idea

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry for not using a comment but my reputation is not high enough so I'm going to answer this way.

You query is pretty simple in terms of tables involved, so there is not much to try (maybe thinking out of the box but I don't have any idea now).

According to the plan it shows that it's using a hash join, and the estimated amount of rows for target and source are 1M and 10K respectively (it's not clear to me from your description). It also shows that most of the estimated cost is due to the scan in the target table and to the hash (71+15 %). So, depending on the amount of rows in the target and source and if you have an index on dbo.FullOrderHeader.Key, it might be possible that forcing a loop join could work better (assuming that the estimates are accurate it should). The higher the amount of rows in the source, the less convenient the loop will be.

You can do that by adding `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)` at the end of the `MERGE` statement before the `;`.

If the amount of source

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spINSERT_FULL_ORDERHEADER
AS
BEGIN
    WITH ORDER_DETAIL_V2
    AS (
        SELECT 'DCMS' AS SOURCE
            ,DC_ORDER_NUMBER
            ,DCMS_ORDER_TYPE
            ,CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID
            ,BILL_TO
            ,CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE
            ,SHIP_TO
            ,SALES_ORDER
            ,MERCHANDISE_STYLE
            ,MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1
            ,CONCAT (
                SUBSTRING(MERCHANDISE_STYLE, 3, 6)
                ,'-'
                ,SUBSTRING(MERCHANDISE_STYLE, 9, 3)
                ) AS MATERIAL
            ,SUBSTRING(MERCHANDISE_STYLE, 14, 2) AS QUALITY
            ,ORDER_QTY
            ,ORDER_SELECTED_QTY
            ,ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY
            ,RELEASED_QTY
            ,PICK_QTY
            ,PACKED_QTY
            ,RELEASED_CARTONS
            ,FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT
            ,TOTE_COUNT
            ,SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1
            ,SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2
            ,SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3
            ,ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS
            ,ORDER_CARRIER
            ,CARRIER_SERVICE_ID
            ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CREATE_DATE) AS DATE) AS CREATE_DATE
            ,LEFT(cast(dateadd(hh, 2, LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                                    '000000'
                                    ,CREATE_TIME
                                    ), 6), 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                                    '000000'
                                    ,CREATE_TIME
                                    ), 6), 3, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                                    '000000'
                                    ,CREATE_TIME
                                    ), 8), 2)) AS TIME), 8) AS CREATE_TIME
            ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ALLOCATION_DATE) AS DATE) AS ALLOCATION_DATE
            ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE) AS DATE) AS REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE
            ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CANCEL_DATE) AS DATE) AS CANCEL_DATE
            ,CASE 
                WHEN DISPATCH_DATE = 0
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DISPATCH_DATE) AS DATE)
                END AS DISPATCH_DATE
            ,CASE 
                WHEN RELEASED_DATE = 0
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, RELEASED_DATE) AS DATE)
                END AS RELEASED_DATE
            ,LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                        '000000'
                        ,RELEASED_TIME
                        ), 6), 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                        '000000'
                        ,RELEASED_TIME
                        ), 6), 3, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                        '000000'
                        ,RELEASED_TIME
                        ), 6), 2) AS RELEASED_TIME
            ,PRIORITY_ORDER
            ,PARTIAL_SHIP
            ,SHIPMENT_CARTONS
            ,SCANNED_CARTONS
            ,STAGED_CARTONS
            ,LOADED_CARTONS
            ,CASE 
                WHEN INVOICE_DATE = 0
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, INVOICE_DATE) AS DATE)
                END AS INVOICE_DATE
            ,SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER
            ,STARTING_WAVE
            ,ENDING_WAVE
            ,CASE 
                WHEN STAGED_DATE = 0
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, STAGED_DATE) AS DATE)
                END AS STAGED_DATE
            ,ORDER_HDR_STATUS
            ,LEFT(HOST_ORDER_NUMBER, 9) AS DELIVERY_NUMBER
            ,CASE 
                WHEN NOT_SELECTED_DATE = 0
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, NOT_SELECTED_DATE) AS DATE)
                END AS NOT_SELECTED_DATE
            ,LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                        '000000'
                        ,NOT_SELECTED_TIME
                        ), 6), 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                        '000000'
                        ,NOT_SELECTED_TIME
                        ), 6), 3, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                        '000000'
                        ,NOT_SELECTED_TIME
                        ), 6), 2) AS NOT_SELECTED_TIME
            ,NOT_SELECTED_REASON
            ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, EST_DEL_DT) AS DATE) AS EST_DEL_DATE
            ,CONCAT (
                DC_ORDER_NUMBER
                ,MERCHANDISE_STYLE
                ,MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1
                ,CREATE_DATE
                ) AS [KEY]
        FROM OPENQUERY(MEMDWPR1, 
                '
SELECT
OHORNO AS DC_ORDER_NUMBER,
OHORTY AS DCMS_ORDER_TYPE,
OHCUPO AS CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID,
OHBLTO AS BILL_TO,
OHCURT AS CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE,
OHSHTO AS SHIP_TO,
OHSAOR AS SALES_ORDER,
ODMRSY AS MERCHANDISE_STYLE,
ODMRS1 AS MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1,
ODORQT AS ORDER_QTY,
ODORSL AS ORDER_SELECTED_QTY,
ODORSH AS ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY,
OHRLQT AS RELEASED_QTY,
OHPKQT AS PICK_QTY,
OHPDQT AS PACKED_QTY,
OHRLCA AS RELEASED_CARTONS,
OHFCCT AS FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT,
OHTOCT AS TOTE_COUNT,
ODSP01 AS SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1,
ODSP02 AS SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2,
ODSP03 AS SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3,
ODODST AS ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS,
OHORCR AS ORDER_CARRIER,
OHCRSV AS CARRIER_SERVICE_ID,
OHCRDT AS CREATE_DATE,
OHCRTM AS CREATE_TIME,
OHALDT AS ALLOCATION_DATE,
OHRQDT AS REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE,
OHCNDT AS CANCEL_DATE,
OHDIDT AS DISPATCH_DATE,
OHRLDT AS RELEASED_DATE,
OHRLTM AS RELEASED_TIME,
OHORPY AS PRIORITY_ORDER,
OHPLSH AS PARTIAL_SHIP,
OHSHCA AS SHIPMENT_CARTONS,
OHSNCA AS SCANNED_CARTONS,
OHSGCA AS STAGED_CARTONS,
OHLDCA AS LOADED_CARTONS,
OHIVDT AS INVOICE_DATE,
OHLDNO AS SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER,
OHWVST AS STARTING_WAVE,
OHWVED AS ENDING_WAVE,
OHSGDT AS STAGED_DATE,
OHOHST AS ORDER_HDR_STATUS,
OHHSOR AS HOST_ORDER_NUMBER,
OHSLDT AS NOT_SELECTED_DATE,
OHSLTM AS NOT_SELECTED_TIME,
OHSLRS AS NOT_SELECTED_REASON,
OHEXDD AS EST_DEL_DT
FROM DSV052BDTA.OHORDR00@MEMWMS2.WORLD
JOIN DSV052BDTA.ODORDR00@MEMWMS2.WORLD 
ON ODORNO = OHORNO
'
            )
        GROUP BY DC_ORDER_NUMBER
            ,DCMS_ORDER_TYPE
            ,CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID
            ,BILL_TO
            ,CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE
            ,SHIP_TO
            ,SALES_ORDER
            ,MERCHANDISE_STYLE
            ,MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1
            ,CONCAT (
                SUBSTRING(MERCHANDISE_STYLE, 3, 6)
                ,'-'
                ,SUBSTRING(MERCHANDISE_STYLE, 9, 3)
                )
            ,SUBSTRING(MERCHANDISE_STYLE, 14, 2)
            ,ORDER_QTY
            ,ORDER_SELECTED_QTY
            ,ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY
            ,RELEASED_QTY
            ,PICK_QTY
            ,PACKED_QTY
            ,RELEASED_CARTONS
            ,FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT
            ,TOTE_COUNT
            ,SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1
            ,SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2
            ,SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3
            ,ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS
            ,ORDER_CARRIER
            ,CARRIER_SERVICE_ID
            ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CREATE_DATE) AS DATE)
            ,LEFT(cast(dateadd(hh, 2, LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                                    '000000'
                                    ,CREATE_TIME
                                    ), 6), 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                                    '000000'
                                    ,CREATE_TIME
                                    ), 6), 3, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                                    '000000'
                                    ,CREATE_TIME
                                    ), 8), 2)) AS TIME), 8)
            ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ALLOCATION_DATE) AS DATE)
            ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE) AS DATE)
            ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CANCEL_DATE) AS DATE)
            ,CASE 
                WHEN DISPATCH_DATE = 0
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DISPATCH_DATE) AS DATE)
                END
            ,CASE 
                WHEN RELEASED_DATE = 0
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, RELEASED_DATE) AS DATE)
                END
            ,LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                        '000000'
                        ,RELEASED_TIME
                        ), 6), 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                        '000000'
                        ,RELEASED_TIME
                        ), 6), 3, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                        '000000'
                        ,RELEASED_TIME
                        ), 6), 2)
            ,PRIORITY_ORDER
            ,PARTIAL_SHIP
            ,SHIPMENT_CARTONS
            ,SCANNED_CARTONS
            ,STAGED_CARTONS
            ,LOADED_CARTONS
            ,CASE 
                WHEN INVOICE_DATE = 0
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, INVOICE_DATE) AS DATE)
                END
            ,SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER
            ,STARTING_WAVE
            ,ENDING_WAVE
            ,CASE 
                WHEN STAGED_DATE = 0
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, STAGED_DATE) AS DATE)
                END
            ,ORDER_HDR_STATUS
            ,LEFT(HOST_ORDER_NUMBER, 9)
            ,CASE 
                WHEN NOT_SELECTED_DATE = 0
                    THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, NOT_SELECTED_DATE) AS DATE)
                END
            ,LEFT(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                        '000000'
                        ,NOT_SELECTED_TIME
                        ), 6), 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                        '000000'
                        ,NOT_SELECTED_TIME
                        ), 6), 3, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(RIGHT(CONCAT (
                        '000000'
                        ,NOT_SELECTED_TIME
                        ), 6), 2)
            ,NOT_SELECTED_REASON
            ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, EST_DEL_DT) AS DATE)
            ,CONCAT (
                DC_ORDER_NUMBER
                ,MERCHANDISE_STYLE
                ,MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1
                ,CREATE_DATE
                )
        )
    MERGE BUSINESSPLANNING_TEST.dbo.[FullOrderHeader] AS TARGET
    USING ORDER_DETAIL_V2 AS SOURCE
        ON TARGET.[KEY] = SOURCE.[KEY]
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE
            SET TARGET.[SOURCE] = SOURCE.[SOURCE]
                ,TARGET.DC_ORDER_NUMBER = SOURCE.DC_ORDER_NUMBER
                ,TARGET.DCMS_ORDER_TYPE = SOURCE.DCMS_ORDER_TYPE
                ,TARGET.CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID = SOURCE.CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID
                ,TARGET.BILL_TO = SOURCE.BILL_TO
                ,TARGET.CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE = SOURCE.CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE
                ,TARGET.SHIP_TO = SOURCE.SHIP_TO
                ,TARGET.SALES_ORDER = SOURCE.SALES_ORDER
                ,TARGET.MERCHANDISE_STYLE = SOURCE.MERCHANDISE_STYLE
                ,TARGET.MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1 = SOURCE.MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1
                ,TARGET.MATERIAL = SOURCE.MATERIAL
                ,TARGET.QUALITY = SOURCE.QUALITY
                ,TARGET.ORDER_QTY = SOURCE.ORDER_QTY
                ,TARGET.ORDER_SELECTED_QTY = SOURCE.ORDER_SELECTED_QTY
                ,TARGET.ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY = SOURCE.ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY
                ,TARGET.RELEASED_QTY = SOURCE.RELEASED_QTY
                ,TARGET.PICK_QTY = SOURCE.PICK_QTY
                ,TARGET.PACKED_QTY = SOURCE.PACKED_QTY
                ,TARGET.RELEASED_CARTONS = SOURCE.RELEASED_CARTONS
                ,TARGET.FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT = SOURCE.FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT
                ,TARGET.TOTE_COUNT = SOURCE.TOTE_COUNT
                ,TARGET.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1 = SOURCE.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1
                ,TARGET.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2 = SOURCE.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2
                ,TARGET.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3 = SOURCE.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3
                ,TARGET.ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS = SOURCE.ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS
                ,TARGET.ORDER_CARRIER = SOURCE.ORDER_CARRIER
                ,TARGET.CARRIER_SERVICE_ID = SOURCE.CARRIER_SERVICE_ID
                ,TARGET.CREATE_DATE = SOURCE.CREATE_DATE
                ,TARGET.CREATE_TIME = SOURCE.CREATE_TIME
                ,TARGET.ALLOCATION_DATE = SOURCE.ALLOCATION_DATE
                ,TARGET.REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE = SOURCE.REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE
                ,TARGET.CANCEL_DATE = SOURCE.CANCEL_DATE
                ,TARGET.DISPATCH_DATE = SOURCE.DISPATCH_DATE
                ,TARGET.RELEASED_DATE = SOURCE.RELEASED_DATE
                ,TARGET.RELEASED_TIME = SOURCE.RELEASED_TIME
                ,TARGET.PRIORITY_ORDER = SOURCE.PRIORITY_ORDER
                ,TARGET.PARTIAL_SHIP = SOURCE.PARTIAL_SHIP
                ,TARGET.SHIPMENT_CARTONS = SOURCE.SHIPMENT_CARTONS
                ,TARGET.SCANNED_CARTONS = SOURCE.SCANNED_CARTONS
                ,TARGET.STAGED_CARTONS = SOURCE.STAGED_CARTONS
                ,TARGET.LOADED_CARTONS = SOURCE.LOADED_CARTONS
                ,TARGET.INVOICE_DATE = SOURCE.INVOICE_DATE
                ,TARGET.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER = SOURCE.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER
                ,TARGET.STARTING_WAVE = SOURCE.STARTING_WAVE
                ,TARGET.ENDING_WAVE = SOURCE.ENDING_WAVE
                ,TARGET.STAGED_DATE = SOURCE.STAGED_DATE
                ,TARGET.ORDER_HDR_STATUS = SOURCE.ORDER_HDR_STATUS
                ,TARGET.DELIVERY_NUMBER = SOURCE.DELIVERY_NUMBER
                ,TARGET.NOT_SELECTED_DATE = SOURCE.NOT_SELECTED_DATE
                ,TARGET.NOT_SELECTED_TIME = SOURCE.NOT_SELECTED_TIME
                ,TARGET.NOT_SELECTED_REASON = SOURCE.NOT_SELECTED_REASON
                ,TARGET.EST_DEL_DATE = SOURCE.EST_DEL_DATE
                ,TARGET.LAST_UPDATED = GETDATE()
                ,TARGET.[KEY] = SOURCE.[KEY]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN
            INSERT (
                [SOURCE]
                ,DC_ORDER_NUMBER
                ,DCMS_ORDER_TYPE
                ,CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID
                ,BILL_TO
                ,CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE
                ,SHIP_TO
                ,SALES_ORDER
                ,MERCHANDISE_STYLE
                ,MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1
                ,MATERIAL
                ,QUALITY
                ,ORDER_QTY
                ,ORDER_SELECTED_QTY
                ,ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY
                ,RELEASED_QTY
                ,PICK_QTY
                ,PACKED_QTY
                ,RELEASED_CARTONS
                ,FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT
                ,TOTE_COUNT
                ,SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1
                ,SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2
                ,SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3
                ,ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS
                ,ORDER_CARRIER
                ,CARRIER_SERVICE_ID
                ,CREATE_DATE
                ,CREATE_TIME
                ,ALLOCATION_DATE
                ,REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE
                ,CANCEL_DATE
                ,DISPATCH_DATE
                ,RELEASED_DATE
                ,RELEASED_TIME
                ,PRIORITY_ORDER
                ,PARTIAL_SHIP
                ,SHIPMENT_CARTONS
                ,SCANNED_CARTONS
                ,STAGED_CARTONS
                ,LOADED_CARTONS
                ,INVOICE_DATE
                ,SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER
                ,STARTING_WAVE
                ,ENDING_WAVE
                ,STAGED_DATE
                ,ORDER_HDR_STATUS
                ,DELIVERY_NUMBER
                ,NOT_SELECTED_DATE
                ,NOT_SELECTED_TIME
                ,NOT_SELECTED_REASON
                ,EST_DEL_DATE
                ,LAST_UPDATED
                ,[KEY]
                )
            VALUES (
                SOURCE.SOURCE
                ,SOURCE.DC_ORDER_NUMBER
                ,SOURCE.DCMS_ORDER_TYPE
                ,SOURCE.CUSTOMER_PURCHASE_ORDER_ID
                ,SOURCE.BILL_TO
                ,SOURCE.CUSTOMER_MASTER_RECORD_TYPE
                ,SOURCE.SHIP_TO
                ,SOURCE.SALES_ORDER
                ,SOURCE.MERCHANDISE_STYLE
                ,SOURCE.MERCHANDISE_SIZE_1
                ,SOURCE.MATERIAL
                ,SOURCE.QUALITY
                ,SOURCE.ORDER_QTY
                ,SOURCE.ORDER_SELECTED_QTY
                ,SOURCE.ORDER_SHIPPED_QTY
                ,SOURCE.RELEASED_QTY
                ,SOURCE.PICK_QTY
                ,SOURCE.PACKED_QTY
                ,SOURCE.RELEASED_CARTONS
                ,SOURCE.FULL_CASE_PICK_COUNT
                ,SOURCE.TOTE_COUNT
                ,SOURCE.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_1
                ,SOURCE.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_2
                ,SOURCE.SPECIAL_PROCESS_CODE_3
                ,SOURCE.ORDER_DETAIL_STATUS
                ,SOURCE.ORDER_CARRIER
                ,SOURCE.CARRIER_SERVICE_ID
                ,SOURCE.CREATE_DATE
                ,SOURCE.CREATE_TIME
                ,SOURCE.ALLOCATION_DATE
                ,SOURCE.REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE
                ,SOURCE.CANCEL_DATE
                ,SOURCE.DISPATCH_DATE
                ,SOURCE.RELEASED_DATE
                ,SOURCE.RELEASED_TIME
                ,SOURCE.PRIORITY_ORDER
                ,SOURCE.PARTIAL_SHIP
                ,SOURCE.SHIPMENT_CARTONS
                ,SOURCE.SCANNED_CARTONS
                ,SOURCE.STAGED_CARTONS
                ,SOURCE.LOADED_CARTONS
                ,SOURCE.INVOICE_DATE
                ,SOURCE.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUMBER
                ,SOURCE.STARTING_WAVE
                ,SOURCE.ENDING_WAVE
                ,SOURCE.STAGED_DATE
                ,SOURCE.ORDER_HDR_STATUS
                ,SOURCE.DELIVERY_NUMBER
                ,SOURCE.NOT_SELECTED_DATE
                ,SOURCE.NOT_SELECTED_TIME
                ,SOURCE.NOT_SELECTED_REASON
                ,SOURCE.EST_DEL_DATE
                ,GETDATE()
                ,SOURCE.[KEY]
                )  OPTION (LOOP JOIN);
END
```

Comment: I tried this, it actually made it worse. 30min plus and it was still runnning, although MERGE went down by 2% to 69%. What I did that improved performance was take out about half of my UPDATE statement columns, which improved performance by 5min (originally 16min).

Comment: Yes, it was a possibility if the assumptions were not valid, index on BUSINESSPLANNING_TEST.dbo.[FullOrderHeader].Key and a low amount of rows in the source. Could you confirm it?
Could you also list all the indexes for the target table?